# How to programatically disable Word Start Screen

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, ms-office

I need to disable Microsoft Word start screen programatically using C# in Visual Studio. I don't want to do it manually like [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8ea152/disable-start-screen-in-word-2013/) .

Anyone can help ?

Comment: I just cannot do it. What I reached is the link attached to my question. Please don't over-criticise !

Comment: This is a user option that cannot be adjusted using vba. A Registry change can alter it for all Office Applications. You can explore that. https://www.askvg.com/registry-tweak-to-disable-start-screen-for-all-applications-in-microsoft-office-2013/  I would hope that you cannot, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a good workaround for it. It is simply to open a new blank document on startup

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (Application.Documents.Count == 0)
    {
        Application.Documents.Add();
    }
}
```